Is this looser case of the maximal clique(connected subgraph) problem also hard?
Suppose $n,m \in \mathbb{N}$. Let $Y = \{1,\dots,m\}^n$. We'll call vectors $(x_1,\dots,x_n), (y_1,\dots,y_n) \in Y$ independent iff $\forall 1 \leq i \leq n, x_i \neq y_i$. There can be at most $m$ vectors at a time that are pairwise independent. Given a set of such vectors $X \subset Y$, the problem is to find maximal subsets of pairwise independent vectors in $X$. In general, $X$ can have $\require{cancel} \cancel{many\,elements,\,ranging \,from\,10^5 \,to \,10^6}$ several hundreed elements. We will have $m,n \le 64$.
Note that if we construct a graph, where each vector is a vertex and the edges are defined by the relation of independence, the problem can be seen as finding maximal connected subgraphs (cliques) in this graph. That's the maximal clique problem, which is NP-hard. But in this special case there's more information. Since vectors are pairwise independent iff they differ in every coordinate, this might introduce structure that can be exploited algorithmically. Still, I can't figure out if this is also a hard problem (although I have the impression it shouldn't be as hard).
I've tried to imagine more useful ways to represent the data, e.g., one could enumerate the vectors in $X$, keep $n$ maps and in each map keep $1,\dots,m$ keys. In the i-th map to the j-th key are assigned numbers $k^{(ij)}_1,k^{(ij)}_2,...$ that represent those vectors for which in the i-th place is written the number $j$. These vectors cannot be independent. Still, I couldn't proceed further from here.
Is there an efficient algorithm for this problem?
Edit1: significantly reduced the number of elements required in $X$. It would likely contain only several hundred vectors.
Edit2: someone proved that this actually is NP hard and as hard as the maximal clique problem. It can be found in this discussion. It would have been perfect to even be able to find any cliques that do have around $16$ nodes when $m \geq 16$. But I assume that would still take $O(|X|^{16})$ operations? (which is huge).

I have the feeling you may be able to exploit the values of $n$ and $m$ in the following way. Say we want to find $S = {s_1, \dots, s_s}\subsetneq X$ such that elts of $S$ are pairwise independents.
Because $(s_i)_i$ are independants on coordinates $1\dots n$ there must be at least one $i^1$ for which $s{i^_1,1}$ is among ${1, \dots,m-s}$. Basically this is saying that they are independent on the first coordinates. So you could also extend this for $i^*_j$ with $j\in {2,\dots, n}$. If $m$ and $s$ are quite close I feel it should make stuff easier

CLIQUE as well as INDEPENDENT SET are both not just $\mathrm{NP}$-hard, but also $W[1]$-hard. It means that it is unlikely that exists an algorithm with running time $f(k)n^{\mathrm O(1)}$, where $n$ is the order of a graph and $k$ is an upper bound on the cardinality of maximum clique. But even more strong statement is given in the book Parametrized Algorithms by M. Cygan et al. at page 485:

Theorem 14.21. Assuming ETH, there is no $f(k)n^{o(k)}$-time algorithm for
CLIQUE or INDEPENDENT SET for any computable function $f$.

Here ETH is an abbreviation for Exponential Time Hypothesis which states that $3$-SAT problem can't be solved in $2^{o(n)}$ time.
It doesn't mean that there is no algorithm solving your problem in $o(|X|^{16})$ time, since in theory there still could be an algorithm taking $\mathrm O(n^{k / c})$ time for some constant $c > 1$. However there are no widely known such results.
P. S. According to terminology I advice you to say maximum clique if you are talking about maximum by cardinality and maximal clique if you are talking about inclusion-wise maximality. So every maximum clique is maximal, but an opposite conclusion is generally wrong.
Also clique is a set of vertices inducing a complete subgraph, i. e., containing an edge between every pair of vertices. At the same time a graph is connected, if there is a path between every pair of vertices.
